# showing log messages from external data source in grafana

Tags: grafana, influxdb, influxdb-python

I know this possibly sounds daft, but can you text show log messages in grafana via an influxdb? I.e. if I have a json data source full of alarm messages can I show them in a grafana data board?

Sorry for the simplicity of the questions

Answer (score 0):

Sure, documentation https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/influxdb/ is your friend:

[image]